# How to correctly order items in mobile responsive column layout?

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

I have an issue with WordPress website in mobile responsive. I have multiple sections with the below arrangement.

> Left side content and right side image ( First Section )
>   Right Side Image and Left side content ( Second Section )

In the mobile version sections going in the same arrangement (Content -> Image | Image -> Content).

But I want arrangement should be quite opposite for the second section in mobile view.

> Image -> Content | Image -> content

I want a layout like this in mobile:

[image: I want a layout like this in mobile]

Layout in desktop version:

[image: Layout in desktop version]

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use bootstrap grid system for those div or use a media query for them specifically for the mobile devices.

I guess grid system would be easy.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      First columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      Second columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      Third columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      Fourth columns
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of bootstrap push and pull. Please check the following code and output or check my [codepen](https://codepen.io/Nirvana11/pen/KeVJKK).

```css
.box {
  background: #fff000;
  margin: 10px 0;
  height: 200px;
  }
```

```html
  
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 push-md-6"><div class="box">Image</div></div>
<div class="col-md-6 pull-md-6"><div class="box">Content</div></div>
<div class="col-md-6"><div class="box">Image</div></div>
<div class="col-md-6"><div class="box">Content</div></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```